# PHP preg_replace() error with regular expression

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have returned a webpage through curl_exec into a string. I am trying to then replace all hyperlinks with the string javascript:void().

The regex expression that I have tested at http://regexhero.net/tester/ is

```
(?<=href=("|'))[^"']+(?=("|'))
```

This works perfectly. When I try and use it in PHP with preg_replace(), I get the error : Unknown mofifier '['

Code snippet is

```
$pattern = "(?<=href=(".'"'."|'))[^".'"'."']+(?=(".'"'."|'))";
$replacement = "javascript:void();";
$result = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$result) ;
```

I also tried just escaping the string like

```
$pattern = "(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))";
```

I am scripting in a Win environment, but it is to go on LAMP.

Thanks for your input

Comment: Is your regex too complicated?  Can't you do `href=["'](\s*?)['"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add delimiters to your pattern. In JavaScript these are the `/` before and after the pattern. You can use the same for PHP, but I like using `~` instead.

```
$pattern = "~(?<=href=(".'"'."|'))[^".'"'."']+(?=(".'"'."|'))~";
```